# Toggle Event Button

Tags: javascript, html

How do you create a button that toggles between to events?

This is the code I've tried

```
function button (text, callback) {
    var but = document.createElement('BUTTON');
    var t = document.createTextNode(text);
    but.appendChild(t);
    var clicks = 0;
    but.onclick = function () {
        clicks += 1;
        if (clicks % 2 !== 0) {
            but.addEventListener('click', callback);
        } else {
            but.removeEventListener("click", callback);
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you need a Vanilla JS solution or is jQuery ok?

Comment: Does it actually need to toggle between two events?  You've already got the code you need - instead of `addEventListener`, call a function for "event 1".  Instead of `removeEventListener`, call a function for "event 2"

Answer (score 0):

As James Thorpe suggests in comments this could be done without turning on/off event listeners.

You could just use your existing click event like so:

```
but.onclick = function () {
    clicks += 1;
    if (clicks % 2 !== 0) {
        callback();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was suggesting, not switching between different event listeners :).  Perhaps with a third argument of "alternativeCallback" so you can call one or the other

Comment: @JamesThorpe Sorry, perhaps I haven't worded it quite right. I'm agreeing with you.